# Fopen() >>> Найти строку по ID >>> fwrite() >>> fclose()

Tags: php, html, javascript

Есть, так сказать, скрипт PHP + Javascript, который я написал, чтобы было понятно, что мне нужно:

```
<?php
$file = fopen('498200115.php', 'r+');
$line = document.getElementById("2015-03-09").textContent;
fwrite($file, "123"); /*В МЕСТЕ, УКАЗАННОМ ПЕРЕМЕННОЙ '$line'*/
fclose($file);
}
?>
```

Как задать PHP команду, которая будет выполняться примерно так:

> Открыть файл >>> `$file = fopen('498200115.php', 'r+');`
>
> Найти в файле '$file' строку `<span id="2015-03-09">787</span>` >>> Как сделать - не знаю)
>
> Изменить её значение >>> `fwrite($file, "123");`
>
> При ошибке выполнить команду Javascript `alert();` >>> `echo '<script type="text/Javascript">alert("Произошла ошибка.");</script>'`
>
> Затем закончить работу с файлом >>> `fclose($file);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через регулярное выражение, как-то так:

```
<?
$data = file_get_contents('myFile.txt'); //sdfsdf<span id="2015-03-09">787</span> dksfj
$file = fopen('myFile.txt', 'w+');
$id = preg_quote('2015-03-09');

$newData = preg_replace('#(id="' . $id . '"\s*>\s*)(.+)(\s*</\s*span>)#', '${1}123$3', $data);
fwrite($file, $newData);
fclose($file);
```